# Hibernate Query without duplicates on two columns

Tags: oracle, hibernate, jpql

I have a table with 5 columns like this:

```
id, name, firstName, job, number
```

There are many records in this table. Now, imagine these records:

```
 - 1 Konan toto doctor  45
 - 2 Konan tata doctor  50
 - 3 Konan toto doctor  60
 - 4 simba popo police  44
 - 5 simba tata police  88
 - 6 pikar popo doctor  99
 - 7 simba popo doctor  72
```

now I want to find only record which job is doctor and get record with no duplicate in (name,firstName) 
(if we have many records with same name + lastName we return only one record , let say anyone)

the result will be

```
 - 1 Konan toto doctor  45
 - 2 Konan tata doctor  50
 - 6 pikar popo doctor  99
 - 7 simba popo doctor  72
```

the record with id 3 is removed because there is duplicate on (name,firstName) the others because we only need job = doctor

What is the Hibernate Query to get the desired results ?

Comment: Why do you have to do this with JPQL? It would be relatively easy with SQL...

Comment: You could also just use a simple group by with JPQL
`SELECT MAX(p.id), p.name, p.firstName, MAX(p.job), MAX(p.number) FROM Person p
WHERE p.job = 'doctor'
GROUP BY p.name, p.firstName`

Comment: @ChristianBeikov: That will produce random combinations of `id` and `number`, which may not be present in the source data

Comment: You are right, something like `SELECT p.id, p.name, p.firstName, MAX(p.job), MAX(p.number) From Person p WHERE p.id IN (SELECT MAX(p2.id) FROM Person p2 WHERE p2.job = 'doctor' GROUP BY p.name, p.firstName)` is probably more appropriate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why this has to be done with JPQL, it seems rather difficult and produce an inefficient query that probably requires a self join. Here's a relatively simple Oracle SQL based solution

```sql
SELECT
  MAX(id)        KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY id) AS id,
  name,
  firstName,
  MAX(job)       KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY id) AS job,
  MAX(number)    KEEP (DENSE_RANK FIRST ORDER BY id) AS number
FROM t
WHERE job = 'doctor'
GROUP BY name, firstName
```

A more standards compliant solution using window functions:

```sql
SELECT
FROM (
  SELECT
    id, name, firstName, job, number,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY name, firstName ORDER BY id) rn
  FROM t
  WHERE job = 'doctor'
) t
WHERE rn = 1
```

This is a special case of the [top N per category problem](https://blog.jooq.org/2017/09/22/how-to-write-efficient-top-n-queries-in-sql/). I recommend using a native query, which you can still map to entities if you really need to.

Comment: I agree with Lukas. You should implement this query in SQL and not in JPQL. 

JPQL isn't powerful enough for these kinds of queries and JPA was intentionally designed as a leaky abstraction. You can use a [native query](http://www.thoughts-on-java.org/jpa-native-queries/) to execute all kinds of SQL statements supported by your database:

    Query q = em.createNativeQuery("Enter Lukas' query here");